# Java library for multicasting rtp packets from a byte array

Tags: java, rtp

I am looking for a java library for converting audio data received from packets to a multicast rtp socket.  The solutions out there such as JMF do not work as the source data does not yet exist since the data is being streamed in.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the byte arrays, all you need is a `DatagramPacket` wrapping it, and a `DatagramSocket` to multicast it with. No need for a library.